# Implementation of the Difference in Difference (DID) model in R with panel data

Tags: r, statistics, dummy-variable

I am trying to implement the diff in diff model in R in order to analyze the effect of a regulation on households.

I have panel data, meaning that I have observations for different  at different periods.
Lets say (for example) that I have below data:

```
Name  Europe?  2000  2001  2002  2003  2004   
A      YES      56    84    95    32   15

B      NO       63    45    9     25   14

C      NO       47    72   123    54   95

D      YES      28    64   874    14  358

E      YES      45    68   48     32  674
```

If the regulation came into force in 2003 only in Europe, how can I implement this using R please?
I know that I have to create 1 dummy variables for the group control (european) and another one for the year when the regulation came into force but how does it works exactly?

Comment: Asking your question on Cross Validated should be more relevent. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference-in-difference) is a good starting point

Comment: You're right, many thanks!